# How does receiver jvm that does deserialization, know which serialuuid has been used while serializing

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, objectoutputstream

How does receiver jvm that does deserialization using objectInputStream, know which serialuuid has been used while serializing using objectOutputStream. Given that sender and receiver are present in 2 different servers.

Answer (score 1):

Because when writing an object to an `ObjectOutputStream` the serialization logic not only writes the actual class name but also the `serialVersionUid` into the output stream.

Therefore the `ObjectInputStream` (on deserialization) can read the class name of the object to read and also the expected `serialVersionUid` of the class.